# Entered date in textbox must reflect in other textboxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, datepicker

i have 2 tables..In my 1st table i have a textbox(txt1) with a date picker.
In my 2nd table i have 5 similar textboxes(txt2,txt3,txt4,txt5,txt6) with date pickers.

My criteria is.

Initially all the text boxes must display todays date and wen i change the date in my first table , all the textboxes in my 2nd table must get changed to the date which i choose in the first .
I need a VB code or a jave script to do this.

i have done for displaying todays date but not able to code for the other case.

```
If txt1.Text = "" Then
                txt1.Text = Format((Date.Today), "dd-MMM-yyyy")
                If txt1.Text <> "" Then
                    txt2.Text = txt1.Text
                    txt3.Text = txt1.Text
                    txt4.Text = txt1.Text
                    txt5.Text = txt1.Text
                    txt6.Text = txt1.Text
                End If
            End If
```

Comment: r u using asp.net control or jquery for date time picker?

Comment: @ajay:i am using asp.net control.

Comment: @Shuttler check other new answer.... it is work......

Comment: @Shuttler check it.........
if you get a sollution then give mark as answer ....

Comment: @pratik Sir i need a VB code and more over i am not using any AJAX controls

Comment: Can we perform these operations in javascript ???

Comment: @Shuttler check my answer.it may help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this on page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            txt1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        }
    } 

here you can get today date  then after get this date on all textbox


protected void txt1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {   
              If txt1.Text = "" Then

                    If txt1.Text <> "" Then
                        txt2.Text = txt1.Text
                        txt3.Text = txt1.Text
                        txt4.Text = txt1.Text
                        txt5.Text = txt1.Text
                        txt6.Text = txt1.Text
                    End If
                End If

 }
```

u can add your condition on `txt1_TextChanged` event of textbox1 when textbox changed this event fire and you get date in all textbox as you need.

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txt1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="83px" ontextchanged="txt1_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.As i have mentioned above i have done it for making the todays date.I need to know ,when i change the date in txt1 it must get reflected in all the other textboxes.Hope i am clear with what i want.

Comment: yes you can get date when change date on this event `txt1_TextChanged`

Comment: u can add your condition on `txt1_TextChanged` event of textbox1 when textbox changed this event fire and you get date in all textbox as you need.

Comment: i have tried that too but it gets changed only when the button is clicked.i dont want that to happen.consider if i dont have any buttons how will it change? i have tried this code            Private Sub txt1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txt1.TextChanged
        txt2.Text = ""

        If txt_photodate.Text <> "" Then
            If txt_photodate.Text <> Today Then
                txt2.Text = txt1.Text
            End If
        End If
    End Sub

Comment: on this change event you can not need buton when you are focus on other text box and set  AutoPostBack="true"

Comment: <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" Width="83px" ontextchanged="txt1_TextChanged" ></asp:TextBox>

Comment: I just tried using autopostback and ontextchanged but the still only when the button is clicked it is getting changed.

Comment: debuge your code .you change tab it is go txt1_TextChanged event and you get it on other value from txt1 textbox@Shuttler

Comment: it is not possible when you change tab it will go txt1_TextChanged event without button press @Shuttler

Comment: Nope i am getting it only after the button is clicked.

Comment: can u please have a full sample code for tat.For atleast 2 textbox?

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            TextBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
            TextBox1_TextChanged(TextBox1.Text, null);
        }
        else
        {
            TextBox1_TextChanged(TextBox1.Text, null);
        }
    }
    protected void TextBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TextBox2.Text = TextBox1.Text;
    }

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnableScriptGlobalization="true"
        EnablePartialRendering="true">
    </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server" 
            ontextchanged="TextBox1_TextChanged"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1"
            Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" />
        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox1"
            Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
        </cc1:CalendarExtender>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <cc1:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox2"
            Mask="99/99/9999" MaskType="Date" />
        <cc1:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender2" runat="server" TargetControlID="TextBox2"
            Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
        </cc1:CalendarExtender>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

add this code it is work

Answer (score 0):

I get your required solution using jquery .Try this.

Add the below code in your head element in Html

```
<head runat="server">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>


     <script>
         $(function () {
             $("#txt1").datepicker();
             $("#txt2").datepicker();
             $("#txt3").datepicker();
             $("#txt4").datepicker();
             $("#txt5").datepicker();
             $("#txt6").datepicker();
         });
         $(document).ready(function () {
             ShowTime();
             $("#txt1").change(function () {
                 $("#txt2").val($("#txt1").val());
                 $("#txt3").val($("#txt1").val());
                 $("#txt4").val($("#txt1").val());
                 $("#txt5").val($("#txt1").val());
                 $("#txt6").val($("#txt1").val());
             });
         });
         function ShowTime() {
             var dt = new Date();
             $("#txt1").val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date()));
             $("#txt2").val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date()));
             $("#txt3").val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date()));
             $("#txt4").val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date()));
             $("#txt5").val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date()));
             $("#txt6").val($.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', new Date()));

         }

</script>
</head>
```

**Note:**
here i take date format like 'mm/dd/yy' if you want any other format you need change your my code.